NavigaionComponent launchSingleTop not working
I have an android application which has two fragment that can open each other. For example FragmentA can open FragmentB and vice versa. But I need to keep only one instance of each fragment and back stack. Somehow, setting launchSingleTop to true in NavOptions is not working. What am I doing wrong and how to fix this issue? The following code shows an example of how I'm trying to apply launchSingleTop
findNavController().navigate(
    NavigationRoutes.SIGN_UP,
    navOptions {
        launchSingleTop = true
    }
)


After some time of research I figured out that launchSignleTop = true does not keep single instance of a fragment in back stack, it just prevents Navigation Component from re-adding a fragment that is already on top of back stack.
So if you have back stack like FragmentA -> FragmentB and then you try to navigate to FragmentB again, it won't add FragmentB to your stack.
And the solution for this problem will be to use popUpTo like this:
       findNavController().navigate(
            route,
            navOptions {
                launchSingleTop = true

                popUpTo(route) {
                    inclusive = true
                }
            }
        )

